# Can we assign a text index to a list object, rather than a numeric index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am merging a bunch of word docs into a list, like this.

```
import os
import docx2txt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# all resumes     
ext = ('.docx')
resume_path = 'C:\\Users\\resumes\\'

resumes = []
# load the data
for files in os.listdir(resume_path):
    my_text = docx2txt.process(resume_path+files)
    resumes.append(files + '----' + my_text + '--END_OF_RESUME--')
    print(len(resumes))
```

I'm getting each file name from 'files'. Now, I can easily find these items in the list, and each looks something like this...

```
aaron.docx----, more text, etc., etc.
sam.docx----, more text, etc., etc.
henry.docx----, more text, etc., etc.
```

Instead of an index 0, 1, 2, etc., how can I create an index like aaron.docx, sam.docx, henry.docx, etc? Or, should the list be converted into a dataframe or a dictionary, and then I'll have indexes? Ultimately, I want to merge two lists together. I tried to zip two lists together and create a dictionary from this, but when I zipped a list with 5 items and a list with 3 items, the final dictionary had just 3 items and 2 were dropped.

Comment: Is a dictionary what you are looking for?     I am too busy today to write an answer with code for you.  But you can easily look up dictionaries in the python documentation and see how to do it for yourself.

Comment: To zip iterables of different sizes you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: Without more context is hard to say, but what you described sounds a lot like a dictionary...

Comment: Jorge Luis, I just stumbled across this concept, based on DrM's suggestion to re-look at using a dictionary. Also, DrM, thanks for sharing your ideas! It's working now!!

Comment: The answer to the question you've asked is "use a dictionary", but you have also included some information about what you want to accomplish that is not very clear. We might be able to offer better suggestions if you add more details to clarify the part after "Ultimately I want to..." -- what two lists do you want to merge? Where do these come from? What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a dictionary to store the data:

```py
import os
import docx2txt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')  # Warnings are helpful for debugging.

# all resumes     
ext = ('.docx')
resume_path = 'C:\\Users\\resumes\\'

resumes = {}
# load the data
for files in os.listdir(resume_path):  # I would personally rename the variable to 'filename'.
    my_text = docx2txt.process(resume_path+files)
    resumes[files] = my_text
    print(len(resumes.keys()))
```

You can then access your individual resumes with `resumes[filename]`.